# centering an 2D image with respect to x,y axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D array with shape (512,512) that looks like this:

[image: my_image]

I'd like to display it with the center point, which is (183., 185.), to be the origin of coordinates, i.e., (0,0).

If I subtract each of those values (183. and 185.), row and column-wise, respectively, the axis don't move, but the values of the arrays change, obviously.

How to achieve that transformation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want just to set different tick labels? Or move your whole plot (then do you want not to plot the area that would go outside of the plotting area?)

Comment: I'd like to set the tick labels so that the center of the "thing" in the plot lies in 0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
tick_step = 100

x_len = my_img.shape[0]
y_len = my_img.shape[1]

xticks = np.arange(0, x_len, tick_step)
yticks = np.arange(0, y_len, tick_step)

ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_yticks(yticks)

ax.set_xticklabels(xticks - 183)
ax.set_yticklabels(yticks - 185)
```